# qsub launch a job from node

Tags: bash, cluster

I have a pipeline that is launched using a command. For some admin/server reasons, that tool has to be launched from a node. That tool triggers all the steps from my pipeline in a file called pipeline.steps. So what I would do is

```
$ qsub -I
$ cd /path/to/my/tool/
$ ./launch-pipeline pipeline.steps
```

The thing is, some steps require to be parallelized on different nodes. The file content of `pipeline.steps` looks like this:

```
step1: 
  write_pbs_script ${NAME}.pbs
  qsub ${NAME}.pbs

setp2:
  continue...
```

Since I am already launching the pipeline from a node, using `qsub` win the newly created `pbs` scripts will obviously fail. How can I manage to launch my pipeline in a node, and from that node, dispatch new jobs to different nodes?